# How to create object in heap without using new operator in c++?

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-management, c++14, new-operator

`new` operator in C++ is used for creating new objects in heap memory. I have no idea if how to create object in heap memory without using new operator. Is it possible, and how?

Also can anyone also suggest me creating object in stack using `new` opeartor in C++?

Comment: Why do you need that?

Comment: _"Also can anyone also suggest me creating object in stack using new opeartor in c++?"_ You don't use `new` to create stack allocated objects.

Comment: Use malloc function to alloc memory  in heap, but this is c style...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Could use placement new.

Comment: @juanchopanza Ah yes, I always forget about that.

Comment: I think this is answerable question, with fairly short answer with 2 parts: First part using `malloc` and placement new, with appropriate warnings about `malloc`, and 2nd part with how to allocate a buffer in stack (for example as fixed size `char[]`) and using placement new for space in stack.

Comment: @hyde placement new operator uses "new" keyword which is not my focus for object creation in heap memory.

Comment: Is it also worth nit-picking that C++ doesn't really define "stack" and "heap"? (The standard only uses storage duration such as "automatic", "static" and "dynamic")

Comment: @AnkitG I that some homework assignment or something, you why can't you use `new`?

Comment: @AnkitG Perhaps you should clarify your question then. So what you want to do is, create an object in a memory region in heap and initialize it without using `new`, or what?Is using eg. `std::make_unique` ok, since it uses `new` internally? And then you want to use `new` to get memory from stack, what exactly you mean by that?

Comment: @hyde the two questions asked to me in an interview and both the questions are independent. std::make_unique is okay.

Comment: What are you asking these questions? Are they interview questions?

Comment: Voters to close: the questions are unclear? No, they're very clear. The reason why he's asking them is unclear. But that's not a reason to close.

Comment: @ThomasMcLeod yes, these were asked by interview panel for C++ developer position in a software firm. I didn't found any solution on web so asked here. I think the questions and reason behind asking are clear now.

Answer (score 2):

In my limited experience with C++, Using new operator is the only way to create common object in heap. HeapAlloc can allocate memory in heap, but how can you create a class in heap without using new operator?

Comment: `HeapAlloc` is non-portable as well - it's part of the Windows API. C style `malloc` should be portable, the real question would just be *why* you would want to use it over `new`

Comment: @xingfu0539 This is not accurate. A `static` C-array allocated with `new` will live on the heap. Otherwise, if at function scope it is allocated on the stack.

Comment: Obviously `malloc` works in C++ and is the primary way to implement `operator new` in many allocators. On the other hand you'll need placement new after that to actually create a non-trivial object.

Comment: @nikaza: That comment doesn't make sense. If it's a `static` C array, it isn't allocated on the heap nor with `new[]`; if it's allocated with `new[]` / on the heap it's not static. It's one or the other.

Answer (score 2):

In modern `C++` it is common to avoid using `new` directly by using the functions, [std::make_unique](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique) and [std::make_shared](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared) which return *smart pointers*.

Eg.

```
class Object
{
public:
    Object(int i): i(i) {}
    // ...
    void do_stuff() { /*...*/ }

private:
    int i;
};

auto object = std::make_unique<Object>(4);

object->do_stuff();
```

Now you don't have to worry about deleting `object`.

Answer (score 2):

To answer one of your questions, you can use placement new to allocate objects on the stack. For example:

```
int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    char buf[sizeof(string)];                // allocate char array on stack
    string *str = new (buf) string{ "I'm a placement new string object" };

    cout << *str << endl;

    str->~string();                          // delete string object
                                             // character array object will be
                                             // automatically deallocated

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use c language in c++ to create objects without using the new keyword.You can create a pointer to allocate to an address in heap memory using malloc:

```
// make sure to include iostream to access the c library so you can use malloc
#include <iostream>
class Rectangle
{
private:
    int length;
    int breadth;


public:

    Rectangle(int l, int b) :length(l), breadth(b)
{
    std::cout << "overloaded constructor called!" << std::endl;
}

void set_length(int length) 
{
    length = length;
}

void set_breadth(int breadth)
{
    breadth = breadth;
}

int area() {
    return length * breadth;
}

int get_length() 
{
    return length;
}

int get_breadth()
{
    return breadth;
}



};

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
// create a pointer object
    Rectangle *ptr;
// allocate object to heap memory using malloc
    ptr = (Rectangle *) malloc(sizeof(Rectangle));
    ptr->set_length(10);
    ptr->set_breadth(15);

    printf("length %d\n", ptr->get_length());
    printf("breadth %d\n", ptr->get_breadth());

// free up heap memory when done using delete keyword
    delete ptr;

    return 0;
}
```